# Material ui how to toggle open sidebar on search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, use-effect, drawer

I have a sidebar that works fine when you click to right button in my navbar, instead of click to button I want to open it when user starts to type in the search input, that because I providing to my component **searchInput** as prop. With this if statement

```
if (!!searchInput) {
   toggleDrawer("right", true);
}
```

in my code it should toggle it to open sidebar when users start to type, but nothing happens when I start to type.

[image: on click it is opening the sidebar]

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";
import { collection, getDocs } from "@firebase/firestore";
import db from "../../firebase";

export default function SearchDrawer({ searchInput }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    right: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMessages = async () => {
      const channels = await getDocs(collection(db, "channels"));
      channels.forEach(async (channel) => {
        const msgs = await getDocs(
          collection(db, "channels", channel.id, "messages")
        );
        msgs.forEach((msg) => {
          setMessages((prev) => [...prev, msg.data()]);
        });
      });
    };
    return () => setMessages([]) && getMessages();
  }, []);
  // console.log(messages);

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
    if (
      event.type === "keydown" &&
      (event.key === "Tab" || event.key === "Shift")
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };

  if (!!searchInput) {
    toggleDrawer("right", true);
  }

  const list = (anchor) => (
    <Box
      sx={{ width: anchor === "top" || anchor === "bottom" ? "auto" : "45vw" }}
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      <List>
        {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Fragment key={"right"}>
        <Button onClick={toggleDrawer("right", true)}>{"right"}</Button>
        <Drawer
          anchor={"right"}
          open={state["right"]}
          onClose={toggleDrawer("right", false)}
        >
          {list("right")}
        </Drawer>
      </Fragment>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nope, I have errors when don't have cleanup function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a function from

```
if (!!searchInput) {
   toggleDrawer("right", true);
}
```

You could change it to

```
if(searchInput && !state.right){
  setState({right:true})
}
```

Comment: Works for me thanks, another blitz question, now I can't type in search input, how can I solve it??

Comment: Could you share the SearchBar code coz I am thinking that has to do with how the SearchBar handles onChange

Comment: Sure just a sec I've edited a bit because I have infinite loop,                      useEffect(() => {
    if (!!searchInput) {
      setState({ right: true });
    } else {
      setState({ right: false });
    }
  }, [searchInput]);

Comment: Just a sec I give you the link from sandbox

Comment: Sandbox died, link to image https://i.postimg.cc/9Xy4xj9b/image.png, also link from official material ui https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field

Comment: Looks correct to me, try putting a console.log inside the onChange to see if the change handler is being invoked

Comment: I think I found kind of solution, need to add **disableEnforceFocus** property, thank you for your help